# what is difference between General Membership Query vs Group Specific Membership Query in IGMP

Tags: igmp

I have gone through various documents over net but could not find what is General Membership Query in IGMP. I can understand Group specific message query like it multicast router send query to for a specific group say 224.10.10.10 and all host interested in this group, reply to the router.

However, how this general query works, and what is its purpose? How clients respond to this query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In IGMP V2;
General query is used to learn which groups have members on an attached network(type:0x11, group address:0.0.0.0).
Group-specific query is used to learn if particular group has any members on an attached network.(type:0x11, group address:group address that being queried)

IGMPv2 Membership Reports are generated by IGMPv2 hosts when they first join a multicast group, and are sent in response to IGMPv2 Membership Queries.